# Grouping a column to another column variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have an issue grouping one column to another.

I have a dataset called bakery and five columns. A column called Items and another is called Daypart (morning, afternoon, evening, night). I want to group the top Items with each Daypart.

How do I do it? [image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have  a link to your actual dataset?  What is your expected output?

Comment: `bakery.groupby(['Daypart'])['Items'].value_counts()`?

Comment: How can I get the top 10 products for each period of the day (morning, afternoon, evening, night)?